# Use the dollar operator ($) after a call of plyr functions

Tags: r, plyr

I'm fitting some regressions by level of factor with `lm` and `plyr` functions, but I find problems when trying to access to the content of the `summary.lm` class.

As an example, I'm running something like:

```
sum = dlply (mtcars, .(cyl), lm, formula = mpg ~ wt) %>%
  llply(summary)
```

This gives a summary for each regression done by level of the `cyl` variable.

Now, if I want to get the *coefficients* for instance, it's easy with `llply (sum,coefficients)`, but sometimes this is not possible. In this example, if I want to get the `fstatistic` element inside the `summary.lm` object, my only chance is to manually write something like `sum$'4'$fstatistic`, since there's no a specific function to get the F-statistic from this class.

Then, a way to use the operator `$`, or a similar function, is desirable. Please note that the code above is just an example. What I'm trying to accomplish here is to select elements from an object like `summary.lm` or a `dataframe` from the output of `plyr's` functions by using the `$` operator.

Comment: How about `dlply (mtcars, .(cyl), lm, formula = mpg ~ wt) %>%
  llply(summary) %>%  \`$\`(\`4\`) %>% \`$\`(fstatistic)`

Comment: This is very nice. Is there a way to generalize it to every level of the `cyl` factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$` as a function by enclosing it in backticks.

```
dlply (mtcars, .(cyl), lm, formula = mpg ~ wt) %>%
  llply(summary) %>% `$`(`4`) %>% `$`(fstatistic)
   value    numdf    dendf 
9.316233 1.000000 9.000000
```

If you want to apply it to all levels of `cyl`  you can use `sapply`

```
dlply (mtcars, .(cyl), lm, formula = mpg ~ wt) %>%
   llply(summary) %>%  sapply(function(x) `$`(x, fstatistic))
             4        6         8
value 9.316233 4.337245  8.795985
numdf 1.000000 1.000000  1.000000
dendf 9.000000 5.000000 12.000000
```